# 2D Tile Camera?

Tags: java, camera, 2d

Hey all. Quick question here. I'm trying to keep the camera centered on the player, but in the code below, the camera so to speak still moves. Any ideas on how to make it stay in one spot?

```
for(int across = player.PlayerX-5; across < player.PlayerX+5; across++) 
        {
          for(int vert = player.PlayerY-5; vert < player.PlayerX+5; vert++)
          {
            //double RANDOM = Math.random();
            if(across < 0 || vert < 0)
            {
            }
            else if(levONE.A[vert][across] == 1)
            {
              g.drawImage(Floor,across*32,vert*32,this);

            else if(levONE.A[vert][across] == 0)
              g.drawImage(Wall,across*32,vert*32,this);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a top-down 2d game with a tile map.  You are trying to render a 9x9 square with the player in the middle?

You have some bracket odd-ness after the 'else if(levONE.A[vert][across] == 1)'  But I think that wouldn't compile in its current state?

Other than that the code looks good, I might start by adding print statements to ensure the data you are getting is what you expect.  Something like...

```
for(int across = player.PlayerX-5; across < player.PlayerX+5; across++) 
{
  for(int vert = player.PlayerY-5; vert < player.PlayerX+5; vert++)
  {
    //double RANDOM = Math.random();
    if(across < 0 || vert < 0)  //might want to check the 'high' bounds here too
    {
    }
    else if(levONE.A[vert][across] == 1)
    {
      g.drawImage(Floor,across*32,vert*32,this);
    }
    else if(levONE.A[vert][across] == 0) 
    {
      g.drawImage(Wall,across*32,vert*32,this);
    }

    //print ("%d ", levONE.A[vert][across]);
  }
  //print ("\n");
}
```

Should give you a nice grid to work with

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
etc..
```

Comment: I got it, and I used something to like what you had. And thanks for the upperbounds thing, I completely overlooked it :D